# Foreach listBox Items

Tags: c#

How can I do a foreach line for every listBox1 items? The reason I want to do this is because I have a list Box of requests

I simply have a button named "Accept all" and need to do a foreach to accept all the values in theren

I havent tryed anything to do with the subject at the moment and all the other topics on stack overflow are unrelevent to me and in diffrent ways

Answer (score 3):

Use a simple `foreach` loop.

```
foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
{
   var request = item.ToString();
}
```

Or you can use `LINQ` and get all items into a list (assuming that all of your item's type is string):

```
var items = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>();
```

Comment: And how would i get the text of this? (The item in the foreach loop) If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Thankyou. Ill mark this as the answer once the question is 10 minutes old.